# Java convert image format with low memory footprint

Tags: java, image, format, scaling

I'm writing a Web application that let user upload images in several formats (e.g. png,jpg,bmp). After the image has been uploaded the system should convert it to "png" and scale it to a predefined resolution.

To convert the image I use the handy method:

```
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(im, type, baos);
```

Here's where the problem start. The first argument of Image  javax.imageio.ImageIO.write is a [RenderedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html). The Java Doc states that the only known implementation is [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

I try to find a way to convert a [java.awt.Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) to a BufferedImage, but it doesn't seems possible. However, it is possible to [draw an image on a BufferedImage](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/Image2Buf.html).

The problem is that creating a new BufferedImage each time is very memory expensive. I can start creating a pool of BufferedImage but I'm looking for clever/news ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Try Thumbnailator library: http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/

Example code:

```
Thumbnails.of("large-picture.jpg")
        .scale(1.0)
        .outputFormat("png")
        .toOutputStream(os);
```

Library offers also much more like scaling, sizing, cropping, rotating, watermarking etc.

Comment: This is a good library, but it also uses BufferedImage.  Are there approaches that don't use BufferedImage?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of Java libraries and SO posts about this.  Did you check them out?

- http://www.fightingquaker.com/sanselan/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiu/
- http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/
- [What is the best java image processing library/approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach)

Comment: No, I didn't check them. Do you have any recommendation for this problem. I mean, converting images with low memory footprint

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't used any of them so I can't recommend anything.  You can probably find some results on Google or whereever, but your best bet is to just try them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could reuse one buffered image over and over again, using [subimage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to size appropriately when it's time to use the ImageIO.write method

Comment: Ahap, that was the original idea (as the question describes)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the implementation of BufferedImage and implement your own (A file-based implementation perhaps?).  These classes are generally pretty straight-forward to read, often 50-70% comments and clearly written.

They give out the sources, why not make use of 'em?

Answer (score 0):

Launch a native converter like netpbm or imagemagick.