# How to automatically generate QR codes with "subtext"

Tags: generator, qr-code, zxing

I want to automatically generate QR codes that display the content of the QR code (a transaction ID) beneath it. Then end product should be a pic (ideally png) with code + text in it.

I have been looking for libs with that capability, but so far was not successful.

Any hints? Thanks!

PS: currently working in Java (zxing), but everything that's practical will do!

Comment: Is this server-side or on a phone?

Comment: Rather server sided. It's important that I wanted to do this in one step, i.e., without using imagemagick et al afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't know a library for a direct solution, but it shouldn't be hard to combine your two requirements (1. generate QR Code image, 2. put some text beneath) in a single program.

I guess you already know how to generate and get your QR Code image. For the second step, manipulating the image, the following SO-questions have useful answers:

- [How to add text to an image in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929524/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-in-java)
- [Java- Write Text onto Image, then Write to Output File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745343/java-write-text-onto-image-then-write-to-output-file)
- [Image manipulation using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629601/image-manipulation-using-java)