# How to add text to an image in java?

Tags: java, string, image, text, graphics

I need to add some texts to an existing table image (png).
Which means that I need to "write" on the image and I need the option to select the text location.
How can I do it?

Comment: What are you using to represent the image? Do you already have the image in some format in java or do you want to write a whole java program that gets an image and returns that image with the text written on it from scratch?

Comment: +1, nice question :-) made me learn something

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It's easy, just get the `Graphics` object from the image and draw your string onto the image. This example (and output image) is doing that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
        "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
    g.drawString("Hello World!", 100, 100);
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
}
```

Output (`test.png`):

[image: output]

Comment: See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) using `GlyphVector` for other interesting text/image combinations.

Comment: How do I save the image on my computer?

Comment: It's already in the code above. Use `ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));` It will write the file (`test.png`) to the current directory.

Comment: @user1441845 Post another question about that, but just a hint, use `JFileChooser` :-)

Comment: Works like a charm :) But this doesn't wrap the text to the size of the image. If the text width is larger than the width of the image, text gets cropped. Is there any way we can fit the text into the image?

Comment: @Rameshwar Good question but as always post another question to help the community! :) (..or look at this [PO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/400676/271357)!)

Comment: Thanks this worked great, how can we change the text color using hex code and font to arial??

Comment: Stacky:  to change text attributes, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html  and also this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html