# How to add a text to taken screenshot in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, webpage-screenshot

My question might be a little bit reckless, but I would like to know if anybody had an experience with adding a text to a taken screenshot using Selenium WebDriver or any other Java library? Currently I'm utilizing:

```
File screenShotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenShotFile,  new File("C:\\XXX\\XXX\\SeleniumScreenshots\\" + "png"));
```

in order to take a screenshot and it's working fine, but sometimes I need to add a descritive text to the screenshot smth like: "This is failed because of this..." What I need exactly is certain location of the page (e.g. global footer, header, burger menu, certain image) that may be found with xpath expression, take the screenshot of that location and add a text with the problem description. If anybody has an idea how this may be implemented please respond with a sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add text to an image in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929524/how-to-add-text-to-an-image-in-java)

Comment: @andrucz Let me check the link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing Much! Tweaking the code from the link provided by @andrucz

```
WebElement failedElement = driver.findElement(<locate your element>);
File screenShotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(screenShotFile);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
g.drawString("Failed because of this!!", failedElement.getSize().getX(), failedElement.getSize().getY()); //Top-left coordinates of your failed element
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
```

Answer (score 3):

To directly draw on the screenshot returned by the driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

// take the screenshot
byte[] img_bytes = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(img_bytes));

// add some text and draw a rectangle
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.setFont(new Font( "SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
g.drawString("My text", 10, 10);
g.drawRect(5, 5, 50, 50);
g.dispose();

// save the image
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("screenshot.png"));
```

If the targeted element is off-screen then you'll probably have to scroll it into the window beforehand:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```