# What are currently the best image processing libraries for Java?

Tags: java, image-processing

I am looking for a java library that can scale, crop images without losing much quality, convert between image formats (png<->jpg), etc.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach) already, but it was asked 1,5 years ago and I am hoping maybe there are any new inventions, as everything mentioned there looks outdated (and scary).

Answer (score 1):

I had good results with ImageMagick for typical work on gifs and jpgs.

Comment: Which java library did you use for it? There is a couple at least.

Comment: I believe we installed the ImageMagick release and forked off ImageMagick commands using the command line, effectively.  I believe we used Runtime.exec().  We didn't run an API at all.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Java Advanced Imaging library](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/downloads/download-1_1_3.html).