# How do i create an image editor in java?

Tags: java, image, mouseevent

i want to create a image editor for cutting multiple parts of the same image, realigning the parts with individual zooming capabilities, creating the image. and be able to return the image specifications to the program. PLease help

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using Graphics2D and BufferedImages. For reference see at [this post](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) .

Comment: Wow that was a speedy reply..THank you. How do i get all this started with some dynamic-ness that can come only from the usage of the mouse!

Comment: @anto:Use `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`.

Comment: Ya i know that, i have been programming with Java for like 10 years but is there any open source image editing library or some example that will give me a kickstart for this small part of my overall project!

Comment: @anto:Above post contains sample codes. Its a tutorial. You can get the examples from there. And for libraries you should read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach)

Comment: @anto: if my answer solves your problem then you should accept it so others can know its a correct answer.