# RMagick-like image processing library for Java

Tags: java, ruby, image-processing, rmagick, jai

Is there any Java image processing library that is as easy to use as and provides the set of functionalities provided by [RMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html)? (I have seen JMagick and unfortunately that is not the kind of library I am looking for.)

EDIT: Please note that the speed does not concern us as such. What we are looking for is an easy-to-use library that provides many common operations built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/), especially [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai). i dont have experience with this libs, but its on my todo list. there are demos somewhere on the site. maybe it is what you are looking for?!

Answer (score 0):

There's [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), which boasts to be the

world's fastest pure Java image processing program

It can be used as a library in another application. It's architecture is not brilliant, but it does basic image processing tasks.

Comment: Speed is not my concern. I am concerned about the ease of using API and number of functionalities provided built-in.

Comment: In other words, ImageJ doesn't cut it.

Comment: So @Umesh, you googled it and copied the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach/617227#617227)? Bad boy!

Comment: @Cidheart I thought you did not see this article so I posted it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pure Java solution, but the [IM4JAVA](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) project works for many uses. Im4Java itself is a pure Java library that uses the commandline version of ImageMagick as its back-end. It's easy to use and exposes pretty much all the functionality of ImageMagick without the dangers of including native code in your app. That means you can safely use it in application servers etc. without worrying that a crash in the native code will bring down your whole server.