# Java Picture Processing Framework

Tags: java, image-processing

1) Load picture from byte array.

2) Verify it's current picture size.

3) Resize Picture according to my needs.

Is there any out of the box Java Framework which can help me to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be this link is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, java's default packages should be enough:

1. To load an image use javax.imageio.[ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).read(...)
2. To get it's size use the getWidth() and getHeight() of the returned BufferedImage object
3. To resize the image, you can: Create a new image (BufferedImage), acquire it's Grahpics objects, set the transformation, and then draw the original image.

Refer to the [java working with images tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found [thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) to be very good.