# Conversion of a byte[] BGRA array into something more useful/speedy (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, colors, byte, raster

I have a byte[] array that contains BGRA raster data (e.g. first byte = blue component, second = green, fifth = next pixel, blue) and would like to play with it.

Specifically, is there a Java class that's already designed to wrap something like this? I'm wondering, because I'd like to make my code as neat/correct as possible, and if Java already has a compiled version that's faster, then I'd go with that.

Even more specifically, I want to transform the byte[] array into 2 arrays, where BGR1[] + BGR2[] = BGR, and A1 = A2 = A. Any suggestions?

I could of course just write raw code for this, but perhaps there is a neater/faster way.

Comment: Start at [Raster](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html) and follow the links out. Happy coding. Unfortunately Java lacks a way of defining a new "nicely packable" type (e.g. "value type") and most methods of dealing with RGB[A] pixels feels substandard for a high-level language.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is speedy, but it is sure more useful. My source data array came from the Color Stream from Kinect, using [J4KSDK](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/index.php).

My goal with this method was to read the binary bytes of an image. I'm sure you can modify it for your own uses.

```
/* Reference imports */
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/* method */
public byte[] getImage(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    int[] shifted = new int[width * height];

    // (byte) bgra to rgb (int)
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < bytes.length; i = i + 4, j++) {
        int b, g, r;

        b = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        g = bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF;
        r = bytes[i + 2] & 0xFF;

        shifted[j] = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
    }

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    bufferedImage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, shifted);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "JPG", baos);
    byte[] ret = baos.toByteArray();

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach) which has responses for good Java image manipulation libraries.