# Java Open Source Image Optimization libraries

Tags: java, optimization, image-processing, open-source

I'm trying to gather information about all java open source libraries which are focused on image optimization.

One of these is [pngtastic](http://code.google.com/p/pngtastic/), but it deals only with png images. Do you know any other similar libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there aren't many open source java libraries dedicated to image optimization. But there are quite many libraries offering image optimization as part of their features.

For example:

[im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) is a pure java library offers interfaces to ImageMagick, which can be used to optimize images.

[ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), it can be used as a library according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach/617227#617227)