# Eclipse - Image Processing Toolbox Available?

Tags: java, eclipse, image-processing

I would like to know if there is an image processing toolbox available for Eclipse (much like the one available for MATLAB)?

I have found **similar** questions on SO.com, but nothing that quite answers my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox gives you facilities to implement image processing using MATLAB's own scripting language. As Eclipse is now a fairly agnostic IDE, such a Toolbox would have to be targeted at a specific implementation language. Do you have one in mind? To my knowledge, no such Toolbox exists for Eclipse. However, there are a whole variety of similar libraries for a multitude of programming languages that give you the same functionality. (Perhaps minus the very good in situ previews)

Comment: Thank you for your very informative response, Andrew; the language I am using is Java.

Comment: In which case, you may find the discussion on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach) useful.