# Android Creating an image from an API response

Tags: android, image, mobile-development, receipt

I am working on an **Android** app that allows users perform some financial transactions, but i need to build receipt from the API response, this receipt needs to be saved as an image on the user device. I am currently programmatically taking the screenshot of the final page but this is not enough as the details are incomplete, on clicking on the save button of the final success dialog, I need to get some details from the response body and dynamically create a receipt that will be saved on the user device for reference, I see some financial institution mobile application do this and i know it is possible. I tried making few researches and i read about Android PdfDocument API [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html). But it won't solve my problem as i need this details to go into an image not a pdf file. Any reference, idea, or code snippet would be appreciated. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025728/how-to-programmatically-create-simple-image-with-text-inside

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107118/is-it-possible-to-create-image-programmatically-on-java-android

Comment: And you can keep following the links in the comments of each of these. I hope this is helpful so you can try a few things.

Comment: Thank you very much @Code-Apprentice , i was able to solve the problem, this resources was very helpful. I appreciate man.