# How to convert bitmap to pencil sketch in Android?

Tags: android, image

I am developing a Image editing app for Android. For this I need to convert my image to a pencil sketch.

Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 4):

You require some image processing library to do that.
You can try [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/index.html) or [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).

For more information, you can refer this SO post: [What is the best java image processing library/approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach)

Answer (score 0):

**TO Convert The Image to pencil sketch you need to apply 3 filters**

1. GRAYSCALE FILTER
2. INVERT THE COLORS
3. GAUSSIAN BLUR

after successfully applying these filters use colordodgeblend function to make pencil like sketch

**Grayscale filter**

```
ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
matrix.setSaturation(0);

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
imgView.setColorFilter(filter);
```

**CODE TO APPLY INVERT FILTER**

```
float[] colorMatrix_Negative = {
        -1.0f, 0, 0, 0, 255, //red   
         0, -1.0f, 0, 0, 255, //green
         0, 0, -1.0f, 0, 255, //blue
         0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0 //alpha};
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.set(colorMatrix_Negative);

ColorFilter colorFilter_Negative = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix_Negative);
```

**CODE FOR GAUSSIAN BLUR**

```
public static Bitmap applyGaussianBlur(Bitmap src) {

    double[][] GaussianBlurConfig = new double[][]{
            {-1, 0, -1},
            {0, 4, 0},
            {-1, 0, -1}
    };

    ConvolutionMatrix convMatrix = new ConvolutionMatrix(3);

    convMatrix.applyConfig(GaussianBlurConfig);
    convMatrix.Factor = 1;
    convMatrix.Offset = 150;
    //return out put bitmap    return ConvolutionMatrix.computeConvolution3x3(src, convMatrix);
}
```

[for more reference](http://howtomakeasketchapp.blogspot.in/2015/10/sketch-app.html)