# Re size image using java programme

Tags: image, image-processing, java

Am having some pictures with large resolution like 4000x3000 . I want to create a java program which can re size the image size to something small like 1000x900 just for an example . Can anyone tell me some particular java library which can help me to achieve this task . It would be really helpful if you can post any link to such kind of tutorial .

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it calling this method that uses Java native classes:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
...

public static BufferedImage resizeImage(Image originalImage, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();

    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, this);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

There are many image types (BINARY, GRAY, RGB, BGR, ARGB, ABGR...). You can choose one (as I did selecting BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), or declare this value as a parameter.
Just have a quick look to BufferedImage class for details.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to Google before submitting a post over here ... http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/, a simple Google will provide you with abundant of resulst, if those doesn't fit your need then you can try asking here.

Comment: thanks Ewe Seong , yes it was exactly what i was looking for . Next time i would surely search on google before posting a question here :)

Answer (score 1):

`java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance` can do that. But more reliable and faster approach is here:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html