# Library to manipulate JPEG in java

Tags: java, jpeg

I'm new to java;

I need to manipulate a jpeg image to do steganography. Can you tell me if there is any library to manipulate jpeg images?

I mean is there is any function to do a DCT or quantization ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach